# IOS Drawing app in Swift - Need to prevent user drawing outside the image lines

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I currently have an UIView which I have implemented methods allowing me to 'paint' upon this. However, I want to add a feature where an image can be selected and the user can colour this drawing in. As it's aimed at a young audience I want to only allow the user to be able to draw inside the image border. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to approach/implement this?

Comment: Search "paint app swift" on youtube, there are a few tutorials about this topic

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should create a custom uiimageview, and draw on that image by implementing touch start/move/end method. By doing this, you can draw inside the image border

Edited: After selecting image you just have to set some flag true / false in UIView (the view contains your image) to prevent draw in that view, and with implementation of touch action in custom UIImageView => you can only draw inside that picture

Or if you don't want to have a step "select image" , just fire some event from your custom UIImageView to your parent View when user start touching on UIImageView -> set flag in parent View true / false to prevent drawing when touches go outside UIImageView

Comment: That sounds like what they have already—the tricky part of the question is the “prevent drawing outside the lines” part.

Comment: Yes, that method would allow me to just draw directly on the image.

Comment: @Downvote: Did i give a wrong answer ? this part of the question alreary said that "However, I want to add a feature where an image can be selected and the user can colour this drawing in." => after selecting image you just have to set some flag true / false in UIView (the view contains your image) to prevent draw in that view, and with implementation of touch action in custom UIImageView => you can only draw inside that picture

Comment: Or if you don't want to have a step "select image" , just fire some event from your custom UIImageView to your parent View when user start touching on UIImageView -> set flag in parent View true / false to prevent drawing when touches go outside UIImageView